# How to use Windows Azure in Indonesia?

Tags: windows, azure, hosting, cloud, azure-sql-database

I plan to implement my website `(asp.net & sql2008)` using `windows azure`, but I have difficulty to do it because `windows azure` has not released yet in my location (Indonesia).

Should someone like to share the solution the same with my problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The question was asked on MSDN and the answer is that it is not possible. The only solution is to wait for Windows Azure available in your country.

[MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsazuretroubleshooting/thread/7ffd8e2a-b907-45df-b500-597dd5ba472c)

Comment: by following my suggested solution, I'm currently hosting 3 **live** solutions on my Azure account, with no issue at all.

Comment: This is normal, your solution uses a U.S. server so you are no longer considered a user of a non-supported country. It's like anything, it is based on the location and inevitably, changing the location unlocks the system. :)

Comment: Correct, but note that Azure only checks your location when you are about to register an account, not after then.  I'm currently using it from inside Cairo, Egypt, and it's working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

for testing reasons, I wanted to create an Azure account, and faced the same here in Egypt.

I've made it by remotely logging into one of our U.S-based servers, and registered from there :) If you can't do so, and need this account badly, and don't have such server, try using [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/).

**Update:** [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) is a proxy-like solution for your internet connection, it will redirect all requests/responses to a node on the TOR network, which consists of volunteers like you and me.
so my solution is simple, we gonna use tor to simulate that you are inside one of the permitted countries, and register your account with ease.

what you gonna need is to install TOR and configure your browser to use it, but my personal recommendation is to install [TOR browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), it's TOR+a Browser that is pre-configured to use it.

you gonna find a nice video on the [TOR browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) page that will give you an overview about it.

give it a try, and tell me what happened.

Comment: Hi Mr. ElSayed, thanks for your suggestion. Could you explain more detail how to TOR works on creating an azure account?

Answer (score 1):

Just run your apps on HK or Singapore Windows Azure Public Data Centers, these are the APAC Data Centers for your region.